# Is R1 R2 and R3 parallel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

or R2 and R3 are parallel then they are in series with R1?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallel of R2 and R3 is in series with R1.  The current that flows through R1 gets divided between R2 and R3.

Answer (score 2):

A general strategy for these questions is to start at the battery and trace the current through the circuit. So, starting from the batter, we can see that the entire current passes through $R_1$. After that, the current hits a split (at the top of the circuit in your drawing), where part of it goes to the left through $R_2$ and the other part of it goes to the right through $R_3$. Both branches of the current then return to the battery. So we can write this as a step-by-step process:

1.) Entire current goes through $R_1$

2.) Entire current gets *split* between two branches

3.) First branch goes through $R_2$ and second branch goes through $R_3$ simultaneously.

It should be evident from this that $R_2$ and $R_3$ are in parallel, and together they are in series with $R_1$.